# (ASP.NET MVC) Will this make my webapp slow if I use GlobalResources for localization only?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance

I have a multilingual site and I want to use Global resources only, I was wondering if it could cause my site runs slower?

Answer (score 1):

I actually made an experience that definitions in Local_Resources are somehow not visible in the code. So I've been using global resources only for a long time.

Performance problems? Why should they be? It's basically only about access level. You do not doubt that private variables in a class as fast as their public alternatives, right?

Answer (score 0):

i have found that there is no real performance penalty using only-global vs only-local resources. However at my coding style global resources allow for better resources management and usability during development.